# Input in predict(), wrapped in a user-defined function - R

Tags: r, user-defined-functions, predict

I am trying to write a user-defined function, which includes the predict() statement. In the predict() statement, I have to specify newdata = ..., and here I have to specify what data I want to use for the dependent and independent variables. However, if I pass the function-arguments (of my_fun) into predict(), I get the error

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'X' not found
```

Does anyone have a clue of how I can use my function arguments in the predict() statement?
I have already tried something like `deparse(substitute(iv))`, but that didn't work.

Please see the function I wrote below.

```
my_fun <- function(riskdrivers, iv, dv, df) {

  #Fit the model
  form <- formula(paste(dv, "~", iv, "+", paste(riskdrivers, collapse="+")))
  fit <- glm(form, family=binomial(link='logit'), data=df)
  summary(fit)

  #Get predicted values
  df$pred <- predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(iv==df[, iv], riskdrivers[1]==df[ ,riskdrivers[1]], riskdrivers[2]==df[, riskdrivers[2]]), type="response")
}

my_fun(riskdrivers = c("A", "B"), iv = "X", dv = "Y", df = mydf)
```

Comment: You should provide an example of `mydf` in order to make your example reproducible

Comment: note also that `data.frame(iv==df[, iv]`  (and the rest) is probably not correct : you probably want a single `=` and not the logical `==`

Comment: how about defining it over two lines `newdata = setNames(data.frame(df[, iv], df[ ,riskdrivers[1]], df[, riskdrivers[2]]),c(iv, riskdrivers)) ;   df$pred <- predict(fit, newdata = newdata, type="response")` (ps i find it more clear to explicitely return something)

Comment: also to include a working example you could do `my_fun(riskdrivers = c("mpg", "wt"), iv = "disp", dv = "am", df = mtcars)`